# Batch NSLayoutConstraint Activation / Deactivation

Tags: ios, swift

Wondering if there is a possibility of creating the following:

I want to define two sets of constraints so I can toggle between them.

For example:

```
let batchConstraintsA: [NSLayoutConstraints] = (constraintA, constraintB, constraintC, constraintD)

let batchConstraintsB: [NSLayoutConstraints] = (constraintE, constraintF, constraintG, constraintH)
```

Then, be able to deactivate and active the different sets.

```
batchConstraintsA.deactivate
batchConstrintsB.activate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `activate(_:)` and `deactivate(_:)` from `NSLayoutConstraint` to accomplish that. You just need to define two arrays with your constraints and then pass each one to the function.

Taking your example in consideration it will become something like:

```
let batchConstraintsA: [NSLayoutConstraints] = [constraintA, constraintB, constraintC, constraintD]
let batchConstraintsB: [NSLayoutConstraints] = [constraintE, constraintF, constraintG, constraintH]

NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(batchConstraintsA)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(batchConstraintsB)
```

You can read more about `activate(_:)` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526955-activate) and `deactivate(_:)` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526066-deactivate).

Comment: var A: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var B: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var C: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var D: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var defaultConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [A, B, C, D]

Error: Cannot use instance member 'A' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Do I instantiate the individual NSLayoutConstraints first with the bang operator, then create an empty array of [NSLayoutConstraint] for eg: var defaultConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

Then append each individual NSlayoutConstraint to the array??

Comment: I don't have the context of that error so I cannot guide you on a precise way, but you can for sure create the array with the variables without the need to append each one individually. I think that your problem is that you are trying to do that on the variable declaration, try doing it on a method like viewDidLoad, for instance.